# Problem with a platform in API_DEPRECATED macro

Tags: objective-c, deprecation-warning

In my application I want to mark some class as a deprecated API. To achieve this I use macro `API_DEPRECATED`:

```
  /*
     * API Deprecations
     *
     * Use to specify the release that a particular API became unavailable.
     *
     * Platform names:
     *   macos, ios, tvos, watchos
     *
     * Examples:
     *
     *    API_DEPRECATED("No longer supported", macos(10.4, 10.8))
     *    API_DEPRECATED("No longer supported", macos(10.4, 10.8), ios(2.0, 3.0), watchos(2.0, 3.0), tvos(9.0, 10.0))
     *
     *    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("-setName:", tvos(10.0, 10.4), ios(9.0, 10.0))
     *    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("SomeClassName", macos(10.4, 10.6), watchos(2.0, 3.0))
     */

    #define API_DEPRECATED(...) __API_DEPRECATED_MSG_GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__,__API_DEPRECATED_MSG8,__API_DEPRECATED_MSG7, __API_DEPRECATED_MSG6,__API_DEPRECATED_MSG5,__API_DEPRECATED_MSG4,__API_DEPRECATED_MSG3,__API_DEPRECATED_MSG2,__API_DEPRECATED_MSG1, 0)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

I use this macro in this way:

```
API_DEPRECATED("UIFont", ios(7.0, API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED)) // here I have a warning: Unknown platform '__API_DEPRECATED_PLATFORM_' in availability macro
```

How I can use this macro to mark my API as deprecated?

**UPD**
API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED is defined in availability.h:

```
/* 
 * API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED is used as a version number in API that will be deprecated 
 * in an upcoming release. This soft deprecation is an intermediate step before formal 
 * deprecation to notify developers about the API before compiler warnings are generated.
 * You can find all places in your code that use soft deprecated API by redefining the 
 * value of this macro to your current minimum deployment target, for example:
 * (macOS)
 *   clang -DAPI_TO_BE_DEPRECATED=10.12 <other compiler flags>
 * (iOS)
 *   clang -DAPI_TO_BE_DEPRECATED=11.0 <other compiler flags>
 */
 
#ifndef API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED
#define API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED 100000
```

---

I've found `NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS`, but this macro only for iOS. I use it in my project, but want to find some universal solution:

```
#define MARK_CLASS_DEPRECATED(MSG) NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 10_0, MSG)
#define MARK_METHOD_DEPRECATED(MSG) NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 10_0, MSG)
```

Comment: API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED is not defined..

Comment: API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED as commented there tells: you could(should) set a compiler flag to define which version is meant. As this is easy to forget later on, its much safer to define a YOUR_UP_TO_VERSION value directly in source.. If there was no compiler flag API_TO_BE_DEPRECATED will be 100000

Comment: No it don't, this comment tells, that you can, change value of this variable in compiler flags to find all places where you use API that marked with soft deprecations. (If you change value, for some iOS version, Xcode will show errors in API calls for any targets that will be greater than the version).

Answer (score 0):

Make a Class only available starting with some specific OS Version.

```
API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))
@interface SceneDelegate : UIResponder <UIWindowSceneDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow * window;
@end
```

Make a Property available only up to a specific Version and give a hint what else to use

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("SceneDelegate:window", ios(2.0, 13.0)) NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2.0, 13.0);
...
```

Define a property as deprecated so it can not be used without warning beginning a specific OS Version.

```
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) ExternalDisplay *externalDisplay
NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2.0, 13.0);
@end
```

Define a method implementation being use-able starting a specific OS Version

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didDiscardSceneSessions:(NSSet<UISceneSession *> *)sceneSessions API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need mark some of my classes as deprecated, your answer is not about it. NOT available. Also I've found solution with NS_CLASS_DEPRECATED_IOS, and I've use it. But I do not understand, why Xcode complains to my using of API_DEPRECATED.

Comment: The macro ios(`From`,`UP TO`) u use needs a version number up to which its rule should be valid.

Comment: Can you make your comment more clear?  If I use 12.0 as UP_TO, nothing changed, but I can't use the API in iOS 13.

Comment: There is also the following macro you could use `API_UNAVAILABLE(ios(13.0))`

Comment: I need just mark API as deprecated (I need to see warning if someone will use it), I do not need remove this API just now. Only warning

Comment: Then i would use `API_DEPRECATED("No longer supported" ,ios(7.0,13.0))`